# Initializing constant variable based on constexpr condition

Tags: c++, constants, c++20, constexpr

How can I initialize constant variable based on `constexpr` condition?

I need initialization equivalent to this non-compilable code:

```
const int x;
if constexpr(cond)
    x = value1; // value1 may not be valid if cond is false
else        
    x = value2; // value2 may not be valid if cond is true
```

Comment: `const int x = cond ? value1 : value2;`

Comment: @康桓瑋 There is no `constexpr` (i.e. compile-time) variant of the conditional expression.

Comment: @molbdnilo: No variant is needed.  It simply works at compile-time.  But requires both branches to be valid, even though one is not evaluated.

Comment: @BenVoigt I would assume that only one branch being valid was the entire point of asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
constexpr int x = []{
    if constexpr (cond)
        return value1;
    else        
        return value2;
}();
```